# git review not working-change id issue

Tags: git, gerrit

I have committed few files and trying git review command.
But it is throwing following error.

```
2016-08-10 04:44:26: Commit message must have exactly 1 change-id.
2016-08-10 04:44:26: Commit message validation failed.
```

Commit message is already  having the change id at the bottom of the message. Still it is throwing error. I am using "git review" command. Please usggest some solution.

Comment: What's in the commit message?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your commit has **more** than one change-id, which is usually a hash. Double-check that - it should have only **1** change-id.

One of the easiest way to do it is doing `git reset --soft HEAD~1` and commit once more.

Comment: I have already tried that one. Still it is not working. It has only one change id.

Answer (score 0):

The *change-ID* **has to be on the last paragraph of the commit**.

If not, Gerrit doesn't detect it. You can be on that case if you have conflict during merge or rebase. Following lines are inserted at the end of commit message.

> Conflicts:
>   file.txt

To correct that, you should change commit description with command `git commit --amend` to manually move change-ID at the last line.

A feature is discussed to change this behavior on [Gerrit Bug Tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=606&q=missing%20change-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Stars%20Milestone%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary)